# How to create a persistant change in an Android button

Tags: android, persistence, android-button

When a user opens my app for the first time I want a button to say 'Begin' and after they first click it I want to change it to 'Continue'.
How do I make this change persist, even after a user has uninstalled and then reinstalled the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **SharedPreferences** ! This thing is there as long as user has not cleared ur app's data in settings.(And i think it stays there even after uninstalling.. :D )
Sth like this for ur case :

```
//someWhere after we have the button maybe onCreate:
SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
if(settings.getBoolean("FirstTime",true))
{
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FirstTime", false);
    myButton.setText("Continue");
}
else
{
   myButton.setText("Begin");
}
```

if u want sth which will be there even after that(clearData thing) you should write the data in a file (sth.sth let's say myData.txt") on sdCard!That would be there as long as user has not deleted ur file on sdCard with a file manager or sth!